# Getting System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object while mocking

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit, nullreferenceexception

I am writing unit tests using xunit and moq for services in a servic fabric application.

I am passing the mocks like this

```
private static DataQueueService CreateDataQueueService(
            Mock<IServiceBusClientFactory> serviceBusClientFactoryMock )
        {
            // Exception is being thrown at this line below
            serviceBusClientFactoryMock ??= new Mock<IServiceBusClientFactory>();
            return new UsageDataQueueService(serviceBusClientFactoryMock.Object);
        }
```

Then test code is ( I have removed the asserts because it is unrelated):

```
[Fact]
        public async Task QueueData()
        {
            // arrange
            Mock<IServiceBusClientFactory> serviceBusClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IServiceBusClientFactory>();
            serviceBusClientFactoryMock
                .Setup(factory => factory.CreateServiceBusClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(It.IsAny<IServiceBusClient>());

            // act
            DataQueueService dataQueueService = CreateDataQueueService(serviceBusClientFactoryMock: serviceBusClientFactoryMock);
           
        }
```

I am getting Null Reference Exception. Please help. Is this much context enough to answer the question or is more details needed?

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov at serviceBusClientFactoryMock ??= new Mock<IServiceBusClientFactory>();

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to do? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I think your problem is `Returns(It.IsAny<IServiceBusClient>()`. Must return either concrete instance or `IServiceBusClient` mock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Alexander Petrov in comments, problem lies in Returns(It.IsAny(). It must return either concrete instance or IServiceBusClient mock.